# What's the best way to format source code on IMs to preserve indenting?

Tags: code-formatting

Is there a way to preserve indenting in instant messengers when you are pasting source code to a co-worker?

In particular I'm trying to write some python code via google talk, but all tabs are removed.

Comment: I would rather post it at some place like "pastbin.com" and message the generated link

Comment: I wrote pastebin for exactly that purpose :)

Comment: BTW I hate that GTalk butchers indenting, but then again I feel the GTalk client has a lot of problems.

Comment: I'm on the fence about this one.  I could see a post about how to easily format code in IMs/e-mails being useful...

Comment: Agree, I think it should be allowed.

Comment: I tagged it as code-formatting

Comment: OK, I voted to re-open, but can the OP reformat the question to be more general?  Maybe expand the scope to all IM clients?

Comment: done, I made it more general but indicated later my particular scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste the code into http://pastebin.com and get a short link to use in an IM or IRC conversation. *(Disclosure: I run that site, "other pastebins are available!" :)*